# Equals(), hashCode() + ORM

Tags: java

Нужно ли в классах ентити всегда переопределять методы equals() и hashCode() ?
И что значит `не используйте ссылки на поля в методах equals() и hashCode() если классы задействованны в ORM` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Перегружать `equals` и `hashCode` в `Entity`-классах, используемых в ORM нужно по тем же причинам, по которым это нужно в других случаях:

- корректное сравнение объектов, полученных из разных источников (для ORM - в разных сессиях)
- корректное хранение объектов в `Hash*` и `*Set` коллекциях

Нежелательность использования ссылок на поля в `equals` и `hashCode` в классах, используемых ORM, вызвано тем, что большинство ORM возвращают не непосредственно объекты вашего класса, а [прокси](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29). Прокси наследуются от ваших классов и перегружают геттеры. Во многих ORM по умолчанию стратегия получения объектов - lazy (ленивая). Это значит, что в момент, когда вы получаете объект, вы получаете пустую прокси. И только когда вы получаете значения полей через геттеры, выполняется запрос к базе, извлекающий значения полей и заполняющий ими объект. Если вы в `equals` или `hashCode` будете использовать ссылки на поля, вы можете попасть в ситуацию, когда в сравнении или вычислении хеша участвует ещё не заполненный объект. Поэтому вместо прямого доступа к полям следует использовать геттеры.

Естественно, вышесказанное относится к ORM, умеющим загружать объекты "лениво", например, к Hibernate. А вот ORM вроде MyBatis грузят объект целиком, поэтому там использование ссылок на поля в методах объекта вполне уместно.

Comment: Почему-то мне кажется, что обращения к базе при подсчёте хэша - это в принципе плохая идея.

Comment: Обращение к базе будет ровно одно - при первом доступе к полям неинициализированного объекта. После этого в полях объекта будут лежать валидные значения, и последующие обращения будут направлены к ним. Впрочем, все ORM, поддерживающие "ленивую" загрузку можно заставить грузить объект явно, в момент запроса. Это спасёт от множества неприятных ошибок вроде "нужно загрузить данные, а сессия уже закрыта", но может отрицательно сказаться на производительности, если объект подтягивает много других объектов по ссылкам OneToMany и ManyToMany.

Comment: Если у нас 100 объектов по 3 поля, то при ленивой загрузке мы 300 раз слазием в базу для подсчёта хешей. Ведь в случае, если мы считаем хеш, то, вероятно, не у одного объекта. Вообще, можно было бы хэшем сделать id. Но если уж у нас туда попали какие-то странные поля, то наверное, стоит обеспечить их неленивую загрузку. Или я где-то неправ?

Comment: Вы правы. Это стандартная дилемма при работе с ORM - что стоит грузить "лениво", а что - нет. Обычно ORM настраивают так, чтобы свойства самого объекта грузились явно, а связанные с ним объекты/коллекции - лениво. Но это сильно зависит от специфики приложения.

Answer (score 3):

**ORM классы лучше** (вот прям очень сильно лучше, если только вам совсем выбора не оставили) **не трогать**, так как они **предназначенны для отображения структуры БД** и только, да и нормальные люди их генерируют, если есть возможность, и с каждой генерацией ваши методы вылетать будут. Hash - это "техническая" эквивалентность, как от прокси объекта считать? И самое главное - зачем?

**Настоятельно рекомендую ORM** и все с ними связанное (репозитории и т.п.) **не пускать дальше вашего ДБ слоя/пакета/модуля, а заполнять свои pojo классы** (или любые другие модельные классы) на месте, пока транзакция еще бежит и тогда весь бред с прокси и т.п. сразу решается, так сказать. И остальная часть приложения никак не зависит от ORM фреймворка, захотели и заменили провайдера своей модели на xml или messages фреймворк и т.д. и т.п.

А так - да, их имплементация - это часть контракта Жабы, только надо понимать, что **hashCode логика сломана**! И лучше объекты эти делать **имутабельными**, т.к. hash коллекции и т.п. не обновят карзину объекта, если его поля поменяются. При сложной иерархии классов смешных эффектов еще больше.

Comment: то есть правильным решением будет делать поля класса-ентити final?

Comment: я просто после каких либо изменений в классе-ентити удаляю и заново генерирую hashCode() и equals(). .. насколько это правильное решения?

Comment: Уменьшать mutability полезно и нужно, но не надо забывать, что вы увеличиваете количество созданных объектов и на это тоже уходит время и ресурсы (и собирать их из памяти). Нужно искать баланс в своих решения между идеальным миром теорий и жестокой реальностью. Зачастую хеширование объекта и не нужно, достаточно использовать HashMap<String, Object> и другие подобные техники.

Comment: Файнал - это полный запрет на изменение, т.б. это насилие, которое бывает необходимо там, где это нужно. Но если люди понимают, что за каждым изменяемым полем лежит обязаности поддерживать связанные с ним стурктуры целостными - то разницы нет )

Comment: кажется, что это очень индивидуальный подход к каждому ентити, вот если с ентити нужно проделывать все операции CRUD тогда, апдейтнут иммутабле объект уже получается, не получится?

Comment: Кто сказал, что все будет просто, не даром в Java есть String и есть StringBuilder и каждому свое место. Если нагрузка небольшая - то имутабле, т.к. это упрощает код и его читаемость.