# Переопределение equals() и hashCode() в Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hashcode

Прочел [статью](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode). Из нее понял, что методы надо переопределять, потому что, к примеру, при получении обьектов из разных сессий у них могут быть одинаковый id, а если мы переопределим `hashCode()`, то они будут отличаться по хеш - коду, правильно?

Еще один момент: вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498390/equals-hashcode-orm) -  на похожий вопрос дали ответ: методы надо переопределять для корректного хранения объектов в `Hash` и `Set` коллекциях. Опять же вопрос почему (если не переопределить будет не корректно, как это не корректно)? Прошу обьяснить понятней.

Comment: Если объект храниться в любой коллекции, то нужно переопределить `equal()` и `hashCode()`. Если  `equal()` не переопределен, то объеты сравниваются по ссылке. Переопределение  `hashCode()` требуется из-за внутреннего устройства коллекции.

Comment: @Igor Gorbunov вопрос то свой решили? Помог? Отметьте ответ, если помог, ну и чтобы вопрос закрыть тоже.

Answer (score 1):

> к примеру, при получении обьектов из разных сессий у них могут быть одинаковый id, а если мы переопределим hashCode(), то они будут отличаться по хеш

Не обязательно, если кроме равных ID остальные поля тоже будут равными, то hashcode будет одинаковый, а лучше почитай эту статью, там все понятно описано https://habrahabr.ru/post/168195/. А здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/128017/ про использование в коллекции hashMap.